# make multiple lists based on pattern python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a .txt file with info on just about each line. I'd like to create a list of everything, and have each list item be a list with each line of info separated by a br. visually, im given this:

```
234
CS434
3.00
M
09/32/394/23 - 232/32/34

435
eS234
4.01
G
09/44/346/01 - 123/23/54

979
js443
3.03
E
09/23/111/24 - 344/23/22
```

and I would like the pprint to look something like this:

```
[
[[234],[CS434],[3.00],[M],[09/32/394/23 - 232/32/34]],
[[435],[eS234],[4.01],[G],[09/44/346/01 - 123/23/54]],
[[979],[js443],[3.03],[E],[09/23/111/24 - 344/23/22]]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> [x.rstrip('\n').split('\n') for x in open('file').read().split('\n\n')]
[['234', 'CS434', '3.00', 'M', '09/32/394/23 - 232/32/34'],
 ['435', 'eS234', '4.01', 'G', '09/44/346/01 - 123/23/54'],
 ['979', 'js443', '3.03', 'E', '09/23/111/24 - 344/23/22']]
```

Or, making sure that the file is closed:

```
with open('file') as f:
    r = [x.rstrip('\n').split('\n') for x in f.read().split('\n\n')]
```